# Check if there is new content online

Tags: ios, web-services

for example, if i update the content of my website how can i make my ios application verify if there is new content and only to make an update IF there is new content available.
I hope i was clear on the question, i apologise for the bad english.

Best Regards

Comment: how do you manage your data in ios? do you use UIWebView or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a timestamp in the html meta tags of your web page.

If app has seen the timestamp before then no update is pending. If new timestamp then do update.

Edit 2: I see you are using wordpress. For example the `all in one SEO` plugin will let  you add keywords to your posts. Use them on the server side. The app can scan your site for the keyword/timestamp

Comment: On my application im parsing a rss feed. Im very new to online features, so how do i accomplish that from within my application?

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that generates a file that contains the date files where last updated. 
Then your iOS app can check this file and download the rest of the data if the date/time has changed since your last update.

Comment: Im using wordpress, the problem is that i have no idea how to accomplish what you just told me :) some more info or something to read about would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

save some data to NSUserDefault, something like, date of your last update, or count of your data in server.